# Issue when both apache2 server and apache tomcat server installed in my linux machine

Tags: java, php, apache, tomcat

I work in both PHP and Java projects, So my ubuntu machine has both apache2 server and apache tomcat server installed.  My problem is, when I run my java application from eclipse, the url is,

```
localhost:8080/MyJavaApp
```

and when I enter credentials and log in the url should be

```
localhost:8080/MyJavaApp/homePage.jsp
```

but the browser some how taking

```
localhost/MyJavaApp/homePage.jsp
```

hence I get error. but when I edit the url by adding 8080 port number, then works fine. But it is annoying to edit my url by adding 8080 every time. Any help is really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I figured it out myself by experimenting. 
In server.xml, in this line,

`<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" proxyPort="80" redirectPort="8443"/>`

I changed the proxyPort="8080" and it works fine.
But I still don't know what the problem has to do with the proxyport, any explanation is really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change the default port for Tomcat to something else, for example 8181

Current versions of web browsers recognize port 8080 like 80, so that's why it's forward you to 80 or cut the port option from URL.

To change Tomcat port open server config file `server.xml` search for "8080", which is the current port in use, and replace it with something else *(make sure the new port not in use)*, save and restart Tomcat.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it didn't solve my issue. I changed the port number still same problem, I had to edit the url by adding 8181 every time to make it work.

Comment: Then you have a url redirect elsewhere, not sure about it.